Transaction Fails When Increasing Liquidity in Uniswap V3 Using Web3.py
Transaction Fails When Increasing Liquidity in Uniswap V3 Using Web3.py
I am attempting to interact with Uniswap V3 on Binance Smart Chain (BSC) to increase liquidity in a position using Web3.py. Despite setting up the smart contract interaction and passing all required parameters, the transaction fails. Here is a summary of what I am trying to achieve and the issues I am encountering.
Objective

I want to increase liquidity for a specific position in Uniswap V3. The liquidity involves two tokens: CAKE and USDT.

I am:



Retrieving the position's information using the positions method.




Calculating the required token amounts for the liquidity increase.




Approving the tokens if necessary.




Building and sending a transaction to call the increaseLiquidity method in the Uniswap V3 Position Manager contract.



Problem
The transaction consistently fails after being sent to the blockchain. I suspect there might be an issue with:
Parameter calculations for the increaseLiquidity method.
Insufficient token approvals.
The smart contract interaction logic.
Code
Here is the core logic for increasing liquidity:
def increase_liquidity(self, position_id: int, amount0_desired: int, amount1_desired: int, slippage_tolerance: float = 0.01) -> None:
    slippage_tolerance = Decimal("0.01")

    amount0_min = int(amount0_desired * (1 - slippage_tolerance))
    amount1_min = int(amount1_desired * (1 - slippage_tolerance))
    deadline = int(time.time()) + 1200  # 20 minutes

    self.approve_tokens(amount0_desired, amount1_desired)

    tx = self.npm_contract.functions.increaseLiquidity(
        int(position_id),
        int(amount0_desired),
        int(amount1_desired),
        amount0_min,
        amount1_min,
        int(deadline)
    ).build_transaction({
        'chainId': 56,
        'gas': 500000,
        'gasPrice': self.web3.eth.gas_price * 2,
        'nonce': self.web3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.sender_address),
    })

    signed_tx = self.web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, self.deployer_private_key)
    tx_hash = self.web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    receipt = self.wait_for_transaction(tx_hash)

    print(f"\nLiquidity increase successful!")
    print(f"Transaction hash: {tx_hash.hex()}")
    return receipt

# Other 
    def get_position_info(self, token_id: int) -> Dict:
        """Get position information from NFT"""
        position = self.npm_contract.functions.positions(token_id).call()
        return {
            'nonce': position[0],
            'operator': position[1],
            'token0': position[2],
            'token1': position[3],
            'fee': position[4],
            'tickLower': position[5],
            'tickUpper': position[6],
            'liquidity': position[7],
            'feeGrowthInside0LastX128': position[8],
            'feeGrowthInside1LastX128': position[9],
            'tokensOwed0': position[10],
            'tokensOwed1': position[11]
        }

    def calculate_amounts_for_liquidity(self, liquidity: int, tick_current: int, tick_lower: int, tick_upper: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        """Calculate token amounts given liquidity"""
        sqrt_price_current = self.tick_to_sqrt_price(tick_current)
        sqrt_price_lower = self.tick_to_sqrt_price(tick_lower)
        sqrt_price_upper = self.tick_to_sqrt_price(tick_upper)
        
        amount0 = 0
        amount1 = 0
        print(sqrt_price_lower,sqrt_price_upper,sqrt_price_current)
        if sqrt_price_current <= sqrt_price_lower:
            amount0 = self.get_amount0_delta(liquidity, sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_upper, True)
        elif sqrt_price_current < sqrt_price_upper:
            amount0 = self.get_amount0_delta(liquidity, sqrt_price_current, sqrt_price_upper, True)
            amount1 = self.get_amount1_delta(liquidity, sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_current, True)
        else:
            amount1 = self.get_amount1_delta(liquidity, sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_upper, True)
        
        return amount0, amount1

    def tick_to_sqrt_price(self, tick: int) -> int:
        """Convert tick to square root price"""
        return int(1.0001 ** (tick / 2) * (2 ** 96))

    def get_amount0_delta(self, liquidity: int, sqrt_price_lower: int, sqrt_price_upper: int, round_up: bool) -> int:
        """Calculate amount of token0 required for liquidity"""
        if sqrt_price_lower > sqrt_price_upper:
            sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_upper = sqrt_price_upper, sqrt_price_lower
            
        numerator = liquidity * (sqrt_price_upper - sqrt_price_lower) * (2**96)
        denominator = sqrt_price_upper * sqrt_price_lower
        
        if round_up:
            return -(-numerator // denominator)  # ceiling division
        return numerator // denominator

    def get_amount1_delta(self, liquidity: int, sqrt_price_lower: int, sqrt_price_upper: int, round_up: bool) -> int:
        """Calculate amount of token1 required for liquidity"""
        if sqrt_price_lower > sqrt_price_upper:
            sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_upper = sqrt_price_upper, sqrt_price_lower
            
        amount = liquidity * (sqrt_price_upper - sqrt_price_lower) // (2**96)
        
        if round_up:
            return -(-amount)  # ceiling division
        return amount

    def calculate_liquidity_for_amounts(self, sqrt_price_current: int, sqrt_price_lower: int, sqrt_price_upper: int, amount0: int, amount1: int) -> int:
        """Calculate the maximum liquidity that can be held with given token amounts"""
        if sqrt_price_current <= sqrt_price_lower:
            return self.get_liquidity_for_amount0(sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_upper, amount0)
        elif sqrt_price_current < sqrt_price_upper:
            liquidity0 = self.get_liquidity_for_amount0(sqrt_price_current, sqrt_price_upper, amount0)
            liquidity1 = self.get_liquidity_for_amount1(sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_current, amount1)
            return min(liquidity0, liquidity1)
        else:
            return self.get_liquidity_for_amount1(sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_upper, amount1)

    def get_liquidity_for_amount0(self, sqrt_price_lower: int, sqrt_price_upper: int, amount: int) -> int:
        """Calculate maximum liquidity for amount of token0"""
        if sqrt_price_lower > sqrt_price_upper:
            sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_upper = sqrt_price_upper, sqrt_price_lower
            
        numerator = amount * sqrt_price_upper * sqrt_price_lower
        denominator = (sqrt_price_upper - sqrt_price_lower) * (2**96)
        
        return numerator // denominator

    def get_liquidity_for_amount1(self, sqrt_price_lower: int, sqrt_price_upper: int, amount: int) -> int:
        """Calculate maximum liquidity for amount of token1"""
        if sqrt_price_lower > sqrt_price_upper:
            sqrt_price_lower, sqrt_price_upper = sqrt_price_upper, sqrt_price_lower
            
        return (amount * (2**96)) // (sqrt_price_upper - sqrt_price_lower)


# main
def main():
    # Initialize the UniswapV3PositionManager class
    manager = UniswapV3PositionManager()

    # Define the target CAKE amount to add (0.1 CAKE)
    cake_amount = int(Decimal(0.1) * 10**manager.DECIMALS_CAKE)

    # Fetch balances to ensure sufficient CAKE and USDT are available
    cake_balance, usdt_balance = manager.check_balances()

    if cake_balance < cake_amount:
        print("Insufficient CAKE balance to proceed.")
        return
    # Fetch position information for the provided token ID (replace with your token ID)
    token_id = 183917  # Replace with the actual position token ID
    position_info = manager.get_position_info(token_id)
    print(position_info)
    tick_lower = position_info['tickLower']
    tick_upper = position_info['tickUpper']
    tick_current = (tick_lower + tick_upper) // 2  # Simplified estimate of the current tick

    # Calculate the corresponding USDT amount based on the liquidity parameters
    _, usdt_amount = manager.calculate_amounts_for_liquidity(
        liquidity=Decimal(position_info['liquidity']),
        tick_current=tick_current,
        tick_lower=tick_lower,
        tick_upper=tick_upper
    )
    print(usdt_amount)
    if usdt_balance < usdt_amount:
        print("Insufficient USDT balance to proceed.")
        return

    # Proceed to add liquidity to the position
    receipt = manager.increase_liquidity(
        position_id=token_id,
        amount0_desired=cake_amount,
        amount1_desired=usdt_amount
    )

    print(f"Liquidity added successfully: {receipt}")


Questions
How can I determine the exact reason for the transaction failure?
Are there common mistakes when interacting with Uniswap V3 Position Manager contracts on non-Ethereum chains like BSC?
Could there be compatibility issues with the smart contract parameters due to differences between Uniswap's original Ethereum implementation and BSC?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Transaction details

For detecting the revert reason, check the function here. If you want to do this manually, use Tenderly.co debugger.
